# Tomcat6 fails to start Linux Mint virtualbox guest

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat6, virtualbox

I'm trying to get Tomcat6 up and running in an Ubuntu guest.
I used the following command to install Tomcat6:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat*
```

at the end I receive:

```
* Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat6      [fail]
incoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat6, action "start" failed.
```

I looked in the catalina.out file in `/var/log/tomcat6`.
Here is the error I find:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8080
```

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
netstat -anp | grep 8080
```

will tell you what process is using port 8080

In all likeliness, it's another tomcat instance that is already installed

Please note that the pid/pname are shown only if you are root (=> sudo)

```
# netstat -anp | grep 8080
tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:8080     0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      2300/java       

# ps -fp 2300
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      2300     1  3 06:02 ?        00:00:29 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dja
```

Comment: after a restart(which i swear i tried already) tomcat seems to be working as desired thanks for the help though.